# How to programmatically create and confirm shipment for an order using ADD Order popup?

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to create and confirm shipment programmatically for a single order. But I am stuck on how to select all the lines that are displayed on ADD Order popup for adding SOLines on Shipments screen. Any help on this?

```
 string operation = SOOperation.Issue;
        SOShipmentEntry shipmentGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOShipmentEntry>();

        BAccountR customer = null;
        INSite warehouse = null;
       PXResultset<SOOrder> objSOOrder = PXSelect<SOOrder, Where<SOOrder.customerRefNbr, Equal<Required<SOImportFilter.referenceID>>>>.Select(this, currentFilter.ReferenceID);
        foreach(SOOrder order in objSOOrder)
        {
            shipmentGraph.Clear();
            var shipment = shipmentGraph.Document.Insert();
            customer = (BAccountR)PXSelect<BAccountR,
            Where<BAccountR.bAccountID, Equal<Required<BAccountR.bAccountID>>>>
            .SelectSingleBound(shipmentGraph, new object[] { }, order.CustomerID);
            shipment.CustomerID = customer.BAccountID;
            shipment = shipmentGraph.Document.Update(shipment);
            warehouse = (INSite)PXSelect<INSite,
           Where<INSite.siteID, Equal<Required<INSite.siteID>>>>
           .SelectSingleBound(shipmentGraph, new object[] { }, "159");
            shipment.SiteID = warehouse.SiteID;
            shipment = shipmentGraph.Document.Update(shipment);
            var addorder = shipmentGraph.addsofilter.Insert();
            addorder.Operation = operation;
            addorder = shipmentGraph.addsofilter.Update(addorder);
            addorder.OrderType = order.OrderType;
            addorder = shipmentGraph.addsofilter.Update(addorder);
            addorder.OrderNbr = order.OrderNbr;
            addorder = shipmentGraph.addsofilter.Update(addorder);

            foreach (PXResult<SOShipmentPlan, SOLineSplit, SOLine> plan in 
                 shipmentGraph.soshipmentplan.Select())
            {
                SOShipmentPlan shipmentPlan = (SOShipmentPlan)plan;
                shipmentPlan.Selected = true;
                shipmentGraph.soshipmentplan.Update(plan);
                shipmentGraph.Actions.PressSave();

            }      

            shipmentGraph.Actions.PressSave();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have difficulty understanding the feature you are trying to implement from the description. Usually you would automate CreateShipment and ConfirmShipment actions to do this.

Perhaps you have to handle a special case, if all that is blocking you is selecting the data from the grid inside the "Add Order" smart panel:
[image]

Using Inspect Element feature, determine the name of the DataView you target by clicking on the grid:
[image]

Use View Business Logic Source to look up the DataView source code:
[image]

From the source code for that DataView, we see that it returns 3 DAC (SOShipmentPlan, SOLineSplit and SOLine):

```
PXSelectJoinOrderBy<SOShipmentPlan,
InnerJoin<SOLineSplit, On<SOLineSplit.planID, Equal<SOShipmentPlan.planID>>,
InnerJoin<SOLine, On<SOLine.orderType, Equal<SOLineSplit.orderType>, And<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<SOLineSplit.orderNbr>, And<SOLine.lineNbr, Equal<SOLineSplit.lineNbr>>>>>>,
OrderBy<Asc<SOLine.sortOrder, Asc<SOLine.lineNbr, Asc<SOLineSplit.lineNbr>>>>> soshipmentplan;
```

With that information we can now iterate the DataView using the Select method:

```
foreach (PXResult<SOShipmentPlan, SOLineSplit, SOLine> plan in Base.soshipmentplan.Select())
{
    SOShipmentPlan shipmentPlan = (SOShipmentPlan)plan;
    SOLineSplit lineSplit = (SOLineSplit)plan;
    SOLine line = (SOLine)plan;
}
```

I used Base member to reference SOShipmentEntry graph in order to get the DataView. This should be used when you are in the context of a SOShipmentEntry graph extension:

```
Base.soshipmentplan.Select()
```

If you have a direct reference to SOShipmentEntry graph instead you can use that directly:

```
SOShipmentEntry shipmentEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOShipmentEntry>();
shipmentEntry.soshipmentplan.Select()
```

**EDIT**

Code for automating the Add Order dialog:

```
shipmentEntry.addsofilter.Current.OrderType = SOOrderTypeConstants.SalesOrder;
shipmentEntry.addsofilter.Current.OrderNbr = "000001";
shipmentEntry.addsofilter.Update(shipmentEntry.addsofilter.Current);

foreach (SOShipmentPlan line in shipmentEntry.soshipmentplan.Select())
{
    line.Selected = true;
    shipmentEntry.soshipmentplan.Update(line);
}

shipmentEntry.addSO.Press();
```

Comment: So I am creating a new process screen to create and confirm shipments for all orders. I am trying to do it programmatically by adding an order using ADD Order popup and saving it which is create shipment and Pressing create shipment creates a shipment. I have edited the question and have added the code which I have written. It creates an empty shipment with no order added to it because, shipmentplan view is empty. Need help on how to add Lines and save

Comment: OK I think I get it, you want to automate the Add Order dialog. I have added code to the bottom of my answer. I'm short on time and can't test it right now but I think it should get you going.

Comment: The basic idea is to replicate the same actions the user would do in the UI.

Comment: Thank you,that worked! I missed shipmentEntry.addSO.Press();